# How to Split two column in same table in SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @abc varchar(max)='5,4,1',
@xyz varchar(max)='1,2,3';

select value[A] from  string_split(@abc,',')
select value[B] from  string_split(@xyz,',')
```

I need this result in same table

```
A   B
5   1
4   2
1   3
```

Comment: Can you supply the code for string_split as well , maybe update the question with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: that link is creating `union` of different strings while OP wants something like `join`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `row_number()` to give unique number to each record of your string, then apply join on behalf of that generated `row_number()`.
Sample is like this.

```
   select [A], [B] from 
   (
       select row_number() over (order by (select 100)) as Slno, value as  [A] from  string_split(@abc,',')
   ) as t1 
   full outer join 
   (
        select row_number() over (order by (select 100)) as Slno, value as  [B] from  string_split(@xyz,',')
   ) as t2 
   on t1.slno=t2.slno
```